# Raspberry Pi video streaming with lowest latency possible via a server to multiple clients

Tags: node.js, video, raspberry-pi, webrtc, low-latency

I want to build a video security infrastructure with raspberry pis.

Please take a look at the rough layout I've in mind:

[image]

What the system should be capable of:

- The RPis need to stream a **low latency** video to the
  webserver, which displays it to all clients visiting the website.
- If a client authenticates he can control one RPi sending commands that gets translated into GPIO commands.
- All RPis should be controllable simultaneously by different clients in realtime.
- Some kind of scaleability (Clients + RPis)

My Questions:

1. I wanted to program everything in node.js. Good idea?
2. Could WebRTC and Sockets.io help me in this project - if not is
   there another library that would help me out?
3. How many clients could a VPS Server (8GB RAM, 4 vCores) handel in this setup?
4. Is it possible to bring the latency down to < 2 seconds or more?

Anything helps! Thanks!

Comment: To the moderator that declined the 'low quality' flag: seriously? do you have no standards?

Comment: @MitchWheat please tell me what I can improve. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It's way too broad. It's asking for library recommendations. It's depends on many unknown factors. Answers would be opinion based. etc... When you have a specific programming question please post it.

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks for the feedback. Will try to improve my questions.